# iOS QR Code Library with Auto Focus Indication and sound

Tags: qr-code, autofocus

I already finished a simple QR Code apps by using ZBarCode library. I can scan the QR Code and capture the data back to my custom view.

I also can add a subview on Scanner view but that is just a layer and I would like to make a "auto focus" box like a red rectangle will blink when focused the QR Code and capture with SOUND.

It seems ZBarCode is not able to make an auto focus effect and capture with sound, is it something I missed or it's the limitation? If so, does any other QRCode library can do auto focus and capture with sound effect?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The ZXing open source library can do that. It is available in an IOS flavor. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/